# In ngx-Charts, How to make tooltips always appear? Instead of appear on mouse-over and then disappear?

Tags: ngx-charts

I am trying to build the stacked bar graph using ngx-charts in angular 4.x. While displaying the data labels, I am using tooltip template and able to display, but I want those labels to show up always (instead on only on mouse-over).

How I can achieve this in ngx-charts?

[image: Sample Stacked Bar Chart]

Comment: Hi @Ajay , did you manage to achieve this in the meantime? I have the same requirement.

Comment: @crollywood Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Nope, we ended up with changing the design

Comment: @crollywood You mean changed style to show values?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Nope, we have those numbers shown only on hover. Product guys agreed that it is good enough.

Comment: @crollywood I moved to another chart component

Comment: did anybody come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i also have same requirement to show value always .what is the library you are using now for angular .

Comment: @arun https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ I'm using this. Its a chartjs wrapper

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya is it possible to show value on pie chart rather than on hover in that?

Comment: @arun Yes, but you have to use external lib for that also. check this out https://emn178.github.io/Chart.PieceLabel.js/samples/demo/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean [showDataLabel]="showDataLabel"